# saveAll() function to load many records taking time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, java-8

I have a saveAll() function which saves parts into the part table and part_audit table. When the record count is low say 1000..it takes 2-3 mins to save and update the table and the job finishes...but when the record count becomes 200,000..the job keeps on running... There is no data in the table inserted too.
Is there any technique/suggestion which I can insert 200,000 records quickly and efficiently into the table.

```
for (int i=0; i<inParts.size(); i++) {
......
    } else {
                        try {
                            Part addedPart =  new Part();
                            PropertyUtils.copyProperties(addedPart, inPart);
                            
                            addedPart.setCreatedBy("System");
                            addedPart.setCreatedAt(new Date());
                            addUpdParts.add(addedPart);
                            added++;    
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            log.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Date savd = new Date();
                
                log.info("start saving");
                partRepo.saveAll(addUpdParts);
                log.info("start deleting staging");
                partStagingRepo.deleteAll();
                
                log.info("done");
```

Comment: Have you made sure batching is really active?

Comment: have used batch_size =50 in application.yml

Comment: Try turn on logging to see that is really being used. And also consider increasing it much more. 50 is not that much.

Comment: sure...I will increase it to 1000 and see if that reduces the time of running

Comment: Also turn on logging so you can verify that the batch mode is being used. And increase the size to even much more.

Comment: sure..I will increase to 10,000 and check

Comment: Its been 2 hrs....and the job is still running and the locks are still present on all the tables

Comment: What is the strategy to generate the `@Id` ?

Comment: @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Comment: thats only for the part entity..but since there is a lock on multiple tables..do I need to verify @Id generation for all the locked tables?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two check three things

- Ensure each insert is not creating a new transaction, this will slow down the insert process.
- Batch Insert indeed happening and the batch size for JPA is high enough to support 200k inserts
- If you have too many indices the write will be slow. Please check if you can reduce this.